# How to print content of a Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, text, printing, tkinter, pdflib

I saw a similar question already asked (a couple of years ago), and it related to the print of a Tkinter Canvas.

I need instead to print the content of a `Text` widget, which may contain also images.

I was surprised/horrified to discover that maybe there isn't a way to do it. I could live with a PDF export.

`PDFlib` seemed to have many drawbacks, but it might be tackled:

1. Price is high

   Then I noticed this [PDFLib Lite](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-lite-7/), which seems to have all I need.
2. Difficult install with a *configure and make* step that didn't want to setup the Python bindings.

   Then I found out that a simple: `yum install pdflib-lite-python`.

In any case, you should install the source, because it contains many Python examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no support in the text widget for printing, or exporting to a print-friendly format.

That being said, if you don't have embedded widgets or images then it should be pretty easy to take the contents of a text widget and convert it to pdf using something like pdflib. While the text widget doesn't directly support rich text formats, it has very good introspection capabilities.

Comment: thanks Bryan. I gave a look to pdflib... seems a bit of a complex and overweight solution, I hope I'll be able to code with it